# The solution is right in front of your eyes

Tags: mathematics, knowledge

Although Julius Caesar could not have solved this equation, the solution is related to him:

$\quad 63XY-14VZ = 8$

What is the solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the solution is

> August

Reasoning

> Caesar Augustus lived from 63 **BC** to 14 **AD**.
>  Notice that **BC** and **AD** are *almost* Caesar cipher shifts of **XY** and **VZ** (by four places) if only we didn't have that pesky W. It turns out however, that "W" wasn't part of the [Classical Latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet#Classical_Latin_alphabet) so, in Caesar's time, this is a legitimate encoding.
>  *August*, which is named after him, is the **8**th month of the year, which is why I think this is the answer.

As others have also mentioned in the comments, the answer could also be

> October (relating to Octavian) which used to be the **8**th month.

Comment: I had in mind two possible reasonings for the number 8, the other being the meaning of rot13 bpgnivna

Comment: In Caesar's time, October was the eighth month.

Comment: ah, yes, misread that. Comments deleted.